postgres partitioning clause too long for pg_restore (but OK otherwise)
On a 16.3 DB, I exported a list partitioned table via pg_dump. Then, on a fresh 16.3 DB, I wanted to restore that table via pg_restore. But it fails, error message from pg_restore is below:
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  row is too big: size 9000, maximum size 8160
Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY schemaname_removed.tablename_removed ATTACH PARTITION schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p21m FOR VALUES IN (21, 28, 29, 30, 31, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 68, 332, 333, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 467, 603, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 630, 634, 637, 639, 645, 646, 647, 899, 912, 913, 915, 941, 946, 949, 956, 957, 958, 960, 961, 962, 963, 1026, 1114, 1116, 1138, 1162, 1163, 1187, 1223, 1225, 1359, 1360, 1374, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1405, 1406, 1413, 1741, 1753, 1800, 1801, 1808, 1809, 1841, 1889, 1921, 1941, 1942, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2008, 2015, 2016, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2042, 2043, 2066, 2070, 2076, 2080, 2081, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2134, 2174, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2237, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2312, 2313, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2346, 2347, 2365, 2371, 2372, 2384, 2385, 2442, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2492, 2493, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2520, 2535, 2536, 2545, 2563, 2564, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2668, 2692, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2715, 2730, 2773, 2774, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2805, 2806, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2827, 2828, 2832, 2833, 2856, 2887, 2970, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2982, 2986, 2988, 2990, 3029, 3031, 3032, 3058, 3059, 3075, 3076, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3086, 3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097, 3098, 3099, 3100, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 3110, 3111, 3176, 3180, 3185, 3187, 3188, 3190, 3191, 3194, 3198, 3199, 3200, 3201, 3206, 3214, 3215, 3281, 3353, 3373, 3402, 3403, 3408, 3409, 3410, 3411, 3412, 3413, 3414, 3415, 3416, 3431, 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481, 3497, 3498, 3523, 3524, 3525, 3526, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3566, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3570, 3571, 3572, 3573, 3593, 3594, 3595, 3596, 3665, 3666, 3704, 3705, 3706, 3707, 3734, 3735, 3736, 3737, 3738, 3739, 3740, 3741, 3779, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3788, 3796, 3800, 3801, 3804, 3805, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3946, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3951, 3952, 3953, 3956, 3964, 3965, 3969, 3972, 3973, 4021, 4083, 4085, 4086, 4090, 4093, 4096, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4103, 4104, 4119, 4122, 4123, 4129, 4130, 4144, 4184, 4185, 4192, 4194, 4195, 4196, 4197, 4199, 4200, 4201, 4225, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325, 4326, 4327, 4328, 4329, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4397, 4398, 4399, 4400, 4401, 4402, 4412, 4421, 4423, 4424, 4426, 4429, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4499, 4502, 4555, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4570, 4571, 4572, 4573, 4574, 4575, 4576, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4580, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4587, 4605, 4606, 4607, 4610, 4612, 4614, 4615, 4636, 4637, 4638, 4652, 4653, 4701, 4797, 4798, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4866, 4869, 4872, 4873, 4876, 4877, 4878, 4879, 4883, 4884, 4891, 4892, 4919, 5002, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 5031, 5032, 5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5065, 5073, 5074, 5076, 5077, 5078, 5082, 5085, 5086, 5087, 5182, 5231, 5232, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5496, 5497, 5502, 5511, 5512, 5513, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 5574, 5575, 5628, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5640, 5646, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5692, 5696, 5703, 5707, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5781, 5805, 5808, 5810, 5811, 5814, 5816, 5820, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5828, 5833, 5834, 5852, 5853, 5855, 5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5910, 5913, 5914, 5938, 5959, 5964, 5975, 5978, 6021, 6022, 6023, 6026, 6027, 6028, 6029, 6030, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6034, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6046, 6094, 6099, 6100, 6105, 6109, 6111, 6113, 6114, 6115, 6116, 6152, 6153, 6158, 6159, 6160, 6161, 6162, 6163, 6164, 6165, 6166, 6174, 6243, 6324, 6325, 6415, 6416, 6527, 6533, 6534, 6539, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6559, 6581, 6582, 6583, 6584, 6631, 6632, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6671, 6672, 6673, 6674, 6675, 6676, 6681, 6690, 6692, 6693, 6694, 6797, 6798, 6799, 6899, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6954, 6959, 6960, 6964, 6970, 6971, 7246, 7247, 7248, 7250, 7251, 7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257, 7258, 7269, 7272, 7273, 7275, 7276, 7504, 7505, 7506, 7507, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7513, 7514, 7519, 7529, 7533, 7534, 7535, 7536, 7559, 7658, 7661, 7665, 7668, 7669, 7673, 7676, 7677, 7678, 7682, 7684, 7716, 7762, 7776, 7779, 7828, 7829, 7845, 7852, 7882, 7885, 7887, 7891, 7893, 7895, 7897, 7901, 7903, 7904, 7940, 7941, 7942, 7943, 8098, 8099, 8131, 8134, 8138, 8141, 8143, 8149, 8150, 8151, 8152, 8153, 8155, 8156, 8157, 8158, 8222, 8241, 8327, 8328, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8470, 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8484, 8487, 8488, 8556, 8910, 8914, 8916, 8921, 8923, 8924, 8925, 8926, 8929, 8932, 8933, 8934, 8936, 8937, 8938, 8939, 9311, 9383, 9385, 9388, 9389, 9391, 9394, 9395, 9396, 9399, 9400, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9405, 9406);

Here is a sample of how I originally created these list partitions (on 14.10, before this DB was upgraded to 16.3 if this makes a difference):
ALTER TABLE schemaname_removed.tablename_removed ATTACH PARTITION schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p49M FOR VALUES IN (49,50,51,159,301,313,336,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,398,422,437,447,470,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,540,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,587,588,589,590,591,592,593,594,595,596,597,598,599,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,686,691,704,729,766,792,827,867,943,950,1099,1202,1306,1371,1447,1528,1664,2142,2267,2370,2469,2584,2711,2851,2972,3070,3227,3582,3715,3902,4019,4169,4313,4429,4538,4706,4842,4980,5115,5253,5397,5802,5928,6063,6219,6337,6450,6654,6781,6904);

What's interesting is that I did not use spaces after the commas: 49,50,51... but pg_restore does: 21, 28, 29...
But even when I manually try to execute where pg_restore fails and remove the spaces, it still has 'row too big' error. You can see the difference gets smaller, but still not working:
-- (1) spaces as written by pg_restore: 
ALTER TABLE ONLY schemaname_removed.tablename_removed ATTACH PARTITION schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p21m FOR VALUES IN (21, 28, 29, 30, 31, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 68, 332, 333, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 467, 603, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 630, 634, 637, 639, 645, 646, 647, 899, 912, 913, 915, 941, 946, 949, 956, 957, 958, 960, 961, 962, 963, 1026, 1114, 1116, 1138, 1162, 1163, 1187, 1223, 1225, 1359, 1360, 1374, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1405, 1406, 1413, 1741, 1753, 1800, 1801, 1808, 1809, 1841, 1889, 1921, 1941, 1942, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2008, 2015, 2016, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2042, 2043, 2066, 2070, 2076, 2080, 2081, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2134, 2174, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2237, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2312, 2313, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2346, 2347, 2365, 2371, 2372, 2384, 2385, 2442, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2492, 2493, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2520, 2535, 2536, 2545, 2563, 2564, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2668, 2692, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2715, 2730, 2773, 2774, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2805, 2806, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2827, 2828, 2832, 2833, 2856, 2887, 2970, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2982, 2986, 2988, 2990, 3029, 3031, 3032, 3058, 3059, 3075, 3076, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3086, 3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097, 3098, 3099, 3100, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 3110, 3111, 3176, 3180, 3185, 3187, 3188, 3190, 3191, 3194, 3198, 3199, 3200, 3201, 3206, 3214, 3215, 3281, 3353, 3373, 3402, 3403, 3408, 3409, 3410, 3411, 3412, 3413, 3414, 3415, 3416, 3431, 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481, 3497, 3498, 3523, 3524, 3525, 3526, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3566, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3570, 3571, 3572, 3573, 3593, 3594, 3595, 3596, 3665, 3666, 3704, 3705, 3706, 3707, 3734, 3735, 3736, 3737, 3738, 3739, 3740, 3741, 3779, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3788, 3796, 3800, 3801, 3804, 3805, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3946, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3951, 3952, 3953, 3956, 3964, 3965, 3969, 3972, 3973, 4021, 4083, 4085, 4086, 4090, 4093, 4096, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4103, 4104, 4119, 4122, 4123, 4129, 4130, 4144, 4184, 4185, 4192, 4194, 4195, 4196, 4197, 4199, 4200, 4201, 4225, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325, 4326, 4327, 4328, 4329, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4397, 4398, 4399, 4400, 4401, 4402, 4412, 4421, 4423, 4424, 4426, 4429, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4499, 4502, 4555, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4570, 4571, 4572, 4573, 4574, 4575, 4576, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4580, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4587, 4605, 4606, 4607, 4610, 4612, 4614, 4615, 4636, 4637, 4638, 4652, 4653, 4701, 4797, 4798, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4866, 4869, 4872, 4873, 4876, 4877, 4878, 4879, 4883, 4884, 4891, 4892, 4919, 5002, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 5031, 5032, 5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5065, 5073, 5074, 5076, 5077, 5078, 5082, 5085, 5086, 5087, 5182, 5231, 5232, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5496, 5497, 5502, 5511, 5512, 5513, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 5574, 5575, 5628, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5640, 5646, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5692, 5696, 5703, 5707, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5781, 5805, 5808, 5810, 5811, 5814, 5816, 5820, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5828, 5833, 5834, 5852, 5853, 5855, 5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5910, 5913, 5914, 5938, 5959, 5964, 5975, 5978, 6021, 6022, 6023, 6026, 6027, 6028, 6029, 6030, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6034, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6046, 6094, 6099, 6100, 6105, 6109, 6111, 6113, 6114, 6115, 6116, 6152, 6153, 6158, 6159, 6160, 6161, 6162, 6163, 6164, 6165, 6166, 6174, 6243, 6324, 6325, 6415, 6416, 6527, 6533, 6534, 6539, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6559, 6581, 6582, 6583, 6584, 6631, 6632, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6671, 6672, 6673, 6674, 6675, 6676, 6681, 6690, 6692, 6693, 6694, 6797, 6798, 6799, 6899, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6954, 6959, 6960, 6964, 6970, 6971, 7246, 7247, 7248, 7250, 7251, 7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257, 7258, 7269, 7272, 7273, 7275, 7276, 7504, 7505, 7506, 7507, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7513, 7514, 7519, 7529, 7533, 7534, 7535, 7536, 7559, 7658, 7661, 7665, 7668, 7669, 7673, 7676, 7677, 7678, 7682, 7684, 7716, 7762, 7776, 7779, 7828, 7829, 7845, 7852, 7882, 7885, 7887, 7891, 7893, 7895, 7897, 7901, 7903, 7904, 7940, 7941, 7942, 7943, 8098, 8099, 8131, 8134, 8138, 8141, 8143, 8149, 8150, 8151, 8152, 8153, 8155, 8156, 8157, 8158, 8222, 8241, 8327, 8328, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8470, 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8484, 8487, 8488, 8556, 8910, 8914, 8916, 8921, 8923, 8924, 8925, 8926, 8929, 8932, 8933, 8934, 8936, 8937, 8938, 8939, 9311, 9383, 9385, 9388, 9389, 9391, 9394, 9395, 9396, 9399, 9400, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9405, 9406);
-- SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: row is too big: size 9072, maximum size 8160
--
-- (2) first space removed
ALTER TABLE ONLY schemaname_removed.tablename_removed ATTACH PARTITION schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p21m FOR VALUES IN (21,28, 29, 30, 31, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 68, 332, 333, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 467, 603, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 630, 634, 637, 639, 645, 646, 647, 899, 912, 913, 915, 941, 946, 949, 956, 957, 958, 960, 961, 962, 963, 1026, 1114, 1116, 1138, 1162, 1163, 1187, 1223, 1225, 1359, 1360, 1374, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1405, 1406, 1413, 1741, 1753, 1800, 1801, 1808, 1809, 1841, 1889, 1921, 1941, 1942, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2008, 2015, 2016, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2042, 2043, 2066, 2070, 2076, 2080, 2081, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2134, 2174, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2237, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2312, 2313, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2346, 2347, 2365, 2371, 2372, 2384, 2385, 2442, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2492, 2493, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2520, 2535, 2536, 2545, 2563, 2564, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2668, 2692, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2715, 2730, 2773, 2774, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2805, 2806, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2827, 2828, 2832, 2833, 2856, 2887, 2970, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2982, 2986, 2988, 2990, 3029, 3031, 3032, 3058, 3059, 3075, 3076, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3086, 3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097, 3098, 3099, 3100, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 3110, 3111, 3176, 3180, 3185, 3187, 3188, 3190, 3191, 3194, 3198, 3199, 3200, 3201, 3206, 3214, 3215, 3281, 3353, 3373, 3402, 3403, 3408, 3409, 3410, 3411, 3412, 3413, 3414, 3415, 3416, 3431, 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481, 3497, 3498, 3523, 3524, 3525, 3526, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3566, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3570, 3571, 3572, 3573, 3593, 3594, 3595, 3596, 3665, 3666, 3704, 3705, 3706, 3707, 3734, 3735, 3736, 3737, 3738, 3739, 3740, 3741, 3779, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3788, 3796, 3800, 3801, 3804, 3805, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3946, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3951, 3952, 3953, 3956, 3964, 3965, 3969, 3972, 3973, 4021, 4083, 4085, 4086, 4090, 4093, 4096, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4103, 4104, 4119, 4122, 4123, 4129, 4130, 4144, 4184, 4185, 4192, 4194, 4195, 4196, 4197, 4199, 4200, 4201, 4225, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325, 4326, 4327, 4328, 4329, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4397, 4398, 4399, 4400, 4401, 4402, 4412, 4421, 4423, 4424, 4426, 4429, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4499, 4502, 4555, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4570, 4571, 4572, 4573, 4574, 4575, 4576, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4580, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4587, 4605, 4606, 4607, 4610, 4612, 4614, 4615, 4636, 4637, 4638, 4652, 4653, 4701, 4797, 4798, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4866, 4869, 4872, 4873, 4876, 4877, 4878, 4879, 4883, 4884, 4891, 4892, 4919, 5002, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 5031, 5032, 5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5065, 5073, 5074, 5076, 5077, 5078, 5082, 5085, 5086, 5087, 5182, 5231, 5232, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5496, 5497, 5502, 5511, 5512, 5513, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 5574, 5575, 5628, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5640, 5646, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5692, 5696, 5703, 5707, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5781, 5805, 5808, 5810, 5811, 5814, 5816, 5820, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5828, 5833, 5834, 5852, 5853, 5855, 5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5910, 5913, 5914, 5938, 5959, 5964, 5975, 5978, 6021, 6022, 6023, 6026, 6027, 6028, 6029, 6030, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6034, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6046, 6094, 6099, 6100, 6105, 6109, 6111, 6113, 6114, 6115, 6116, 6152, 6153, 6158, 6159, 6160, 6161, 6162, 6163, 6164, 6165, 6166, 6174, 6243, 6324, 6325, 6415, 6416, 6527, 6533, 6534, 6539, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6559, 6581, 6582, 6583, 6584, 6631, 6632, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6671, 6672, 6673, 6674, 6675, 6676, 6681, 6690, 6692, 6693, 6694, 6797, 6798, 6799, 6899, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6954, 6959, 6960, 6964, 6970, 6971, 7246, 7247, 7248, 7250, 7251, 7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257, 7258, 7269, 7272, 7273, 7275, 7276, 7504, 7505, 7506, 7507, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7513, 7514, 7519, 7529, 7533, 7534, 7535, 7536, 7559, 7658, 7661, 7665, 7668, 7669, 7673, 7676, 7677, 7678, 7682, 7684, 7716, 7762, 7776, 7779, 7828, 7829, 7845, 7852, 7882, 7885, 7887, 7891, 7893, 7895, 7897, 7901, 7903, 7904, 7940, 7941, 7942, 7943, 8098, 8099, 8131, 8134, 8138, 8141, 8143, 8149, 8150, 8151, 8152, 8153, 8155, 8156, 8157, 8158, 8222, 8241, 8327, 8328, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8470, 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8484, 8487, 8488, 8556, 8910, 8914, 8916, 8921, 8923, 8924, 8925, 8926, 8929, 8932, 8933, 8934, 8936, 8937, 8938, 8939, 9311, 9383, 9385, 9388, 9389, 9391, 9394, 9395, 9396, 9399, 9400, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9405, 9406);
-- SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: row is too big: size 9064, maximum size 8160
--
-- (3) all spaces removed
ALTER TABLE ONLY schemaname_removed.tablename_removed ATTACH PARTITION schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p21m FOR VALUES IN (21,28,29,30,31,39,40,41,42,43,44,68,332,333,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,467,603,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,630,634,637,639,645,646,647,899,912,913,915,941,946,949,956,957,958,960,961,962,963,1026,1114,1116,1138,1162,1163,1187,1223,1225,1359,1360,1374,1391,1392,1393,1405,1406,1413,1741,1753,1800,1801,1808,1809,1841,1889,1921,1941,1942,1970,1971,1972,1997,1999,2002,2003,2008,2015,2016,2019,2020,2022,2023,2024,2042,2043,2066,2070,2076,2080,2081,2129,2130,2131,2132,2134,2174,2197,2198,2199,2200,2203,2204,2205,2211,2212,2213,2214,2237,2289,2290,2291,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297,2298,2299,2300,2301,2312,2313,2318,2319,2320,2321,2322,2323,2325,2326,2327,2333,2334,2335,2336,2346,2347,2365,2371,2372,2384,2385,2442,2463,2464,2465,2466,2492,2493,2500,2501,2502,2505,2506,2507,2508,2509,2510,2511,2520,2535,2536,2545,2563,2564,2585,2586,2587,2588,2600,2601,2602,2603,2604,2605,2606,2609,2610,2611,2612,2613,2614,2615,2616,2617,2668,2692,2697,2698,2699,2701,2702,2703,2715,2730,2773,2774,2783,2784,2785,2786,2805,2806,2812,2813,2814,2815,2827,2828,2832,2833,2856,2887,2970,2972,2973,2974,2982,2986,2988,2990,3029,3031,3032,3058,3059,3075,3076,3079,3080,3081,3086,3087,3088,3089,3090,3091,3092,3093,3094,3095,3096,3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3102,3103,3104,3105,3106,3107,3108,3109,3110,3111,3176,3180,3185,3187,3188,3190,3191,3194,3198,3199,3200,3201,3206,3214,3215,3281,3353,3373,3402,3403,3408,3409,3410,3411,3412,3413,3414,3415,3416,3431,3478,3479,3480,3481,3497,3498,3523,3524,3525,3526,3527,3528,3529,3530,3566,3567,3568,3569,3570,3571,3572,3573,3593,3594,3595,3596,3665,3666,3704,3705,3706,3707,3734,3735,3736,3737,3738,3739,3740,3741,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3788,3796,3800,3801,3804,3805,3916,3917,3918,3919,3920,3921,3922,3923,3924,3925,3946,3947,3948,3949,3950,3951,3952,3953,3956,3964,3965,3969,3972,3973,4021,4083,4085,4086,4090,4093,4096,4098,4099,4100,4103,4104,4119,4122,4123,4129,4130,4144,4184,4185,4192,4194,4195,4196,4197,4199,4200,4201,4225,4320,4321,4322,4323,4324,4325,4326,4327,4328,4329,4394,4395,4396,4397,4398,4399,4400,4401,4402,4412,4421,4423,4424,4426,4429,4430,4431,4432,4499,4502,4555,4560,4561,4562,4563,4564,4565,4566,4567,4568,4569,4570,4571,4572,4573,4574,4575,4576,4577,4578,4579,4580,4581,4582,4583,4584,4587,4605,4606,4607,4610,4612,4614,4615,4636,4637,4638,4652,4653,4701,4797,4798,4799,4800,4801,4802,4803,4804,4805,4806,4807,4808,4809,4810,4866,4869,4872,4873,4876,4877,4878,4879,4883,4884,4891,4892,4919,5002,5006,5007,5008,5009,5010,5011,5012,5013,5014,5015,5016,5017,5018,5024,5031,5032,5033,5034,5035,5036,5037,5065,5073,5074,5076,5077,5078,5082,5085,5086,5087,5182,5231,5232,5264,5265,5266,5267,5496,5497,5502,5511,5512,5513,5515,5516,5517,5518,5519,5520,5521,5522,5523,5574,5575,5628,5636,5637,5638,5640,5646,5648,5649,5650,5651,5692,5696,5703,5707,5724,5725,5726,5727,5728,5729,5730,5731,5732,5733,5734,5735,5736,5781,5805,5808,5810,5811,5814,5816,5820,5823,5824,5825,5828,5833,5834,5852,5853,5855,5865,5866,5867,5868,5910,5913,5914,5938,5959,5964,5975,5978,6021,6022,6023,6026,6027,6028,6029,6030,6031,6032,6033,6034,6035,6036,6037,6038,6046,6094,6099,6100,6105,6109,6111,6113,6114,6115,6116,6152,6153,6158,6159,6160,6161,6162,6163,6164,6165,6166,6174,6243,6324,6325,6415,6416,6527,6533,6534,6539,6543,6544,6545,6546,6547,6559,6581,6582,6583,6584,6631,6632,6666,6667,6668,6669,6671,6672,6673,6674,6675,6676,6681,6690,6692,6693,6694,6797,6798,6799,6899,6944,6945,6946,6947,6948,6949,6950,6954,6959,6960,6964,6970,6971,7246,7247,7248,7250,7251,7252,7253,7254,7255,7256,7257,7258,7269,7272,7273,7275,7276,7504,7505,7506,7507,7508,7509,7510,7511,7512,7513,7514,7519,7529,7533,7534,7535,7536,7559,7658,7661,7665,7668,7669,7673,7676,7677,7678,7682,7684,7716,7762,7776,7779,7828,7829,7845,7852,7882,7885,7887,7891,7893,7895,7897,7901,7903,7904,7940,7941,7942,7943,8098,8099,8131,8134,8138,8141,8143,8149,8150,8151,8152,8153,8155,8156,8157,8158,8222,8241,8327,8328,8465,8466,8467,8470,8473,8474,8475,8476,8477,8484,8487,8488,8556,8910,8914,8916,8921,8923,8924,8925,8926,8929,8932,8933,8934,8936,8937,8938,8939,9311,9383,9385,9388,9389,9391,9394,9395,9396,9399,9400,9401,9402,9403,9405,9406);
-- SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: row is too big: size 8904, maximum size 8160

To 'proof' that my 'too long' partition is working, here is the \d output of the working DB:
infonova=> \d+ schemaname_removed.tablename_removed

                      Partitioned table "schemaname_removed.tablename_removed"
            [...]
Partitions: schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p1 FOR VALUES IN (1),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p10000 FOR VALUES IN (10000),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p10001 FOR VALUES IN (10001),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p10002 FOR VALUES IN (10002),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p10003 FOR VALUES IN (10003),
            [...]
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p2192 FOR VALUES IN (2192),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p21m FOR VALUES IN (21, 28, 29, 30, 31, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 68, 332, 333, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 467, 603, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 630, 634, 637, 639, 645, 646, 647, 899, 912, 913, 915, 941, 946, 949, 956, 957, 958, 960, 961, 962, 963, 1026, 1114, 1116, 1138, 1162, 1163, 1187, 1223, 1225, 1359, 1360, 1374, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1405, 1406, 1413, 1741, 1753, 1800, 1801, 1808, 1809, 1841, 1889, 1921, 1941, 1942, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2008, 2015, 2016, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2042, 2043, 2066, 2070, 2076, 2080, 2081, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2134, 2174, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2237, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2312, 2313, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2346, 2347, 2365, 2371, 2372, 2384, 2385, 2442, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2492, 2493, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2520, 2535, 2536, 2545, 2563, 2564, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2668, 2692, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2715, 2730, 2773, 2774, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2805, 2806, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2827, 2828, 2832, 2833, 2856, 2887, 2970, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2982, 2986, 2988, 2990, 3029, 3031, 3032, 3058, 3059, 3075, 3076, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3086, 3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097, 3098, 3099, 3100, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 3110, 3111, 3176, 3180, 3185, 3187, 3188, 3190, 3191, 3194, 3198, 3199, 3200, 3201, 3206, 3214, 3215, 3281, 3353, 3373, 3402, 3403, 3408, 3409, 3410, 3411, 3412, 3413, 3414, 3415, 3416, 3431, 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481, 3497, 3498, 3523, 3524, 3525, 3526, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3566, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3570, 3571, 3572, 3573, 3593, 3594, 3595, 3596, 3665, 3666, 3704, 3705, 3706, 3707, 3734, 3735, 3736, 3737, 3738, 3739, 3740, 3741, 3779, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3788, 3796, 3800, 3801, 3804, 3805, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3946, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3951, 3952, 3953, 3956, 3964, 3965, 3969, 3972, 3973, 4021, 4083, 4085, 4086, 4090, 4093, 4096, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4103, 4104, 4119, 4122, 4123, 4129, 4130, 4144, 4184, 4185, 4192, 4194, 4195, 4196, 4197, 4199, 4200, 4201, 4225, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325, 4326, 4327, 4328, 4329, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4397, 4398, 4399, 4400, 4401, 4402, 4412, 4421, 4423, 4424, 4426, 4429, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4499, 4502, 4555, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4570, 4571, 4572, 4573, 4574, 4575, 4576, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4580, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4587, 4605, 4606, 4607, 4610, 4612, 4614, 4615, 4636, 4637, 4638, 4652, 4653, 4701, 4797, 4798, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4866, 4869, 4872, 4873, 4876, 4877, 4878, 4879, 4883, 4884, 4891, 4892, 4919, 5002, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 5031, 5032, 5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5065, 5073, 5074, 5076, 5077, 5078, 5082, 5085, 5086, 5087, 5182, 5231, 5232, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5496, 5497, 5502, 5511, 5512, 5513, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 5574, 5575, 5628, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5640, 5646, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5692, 5696, 5703, 5707, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5781, 5805, 5808, 5810, 5811, 5814, 5816, 5820, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5828, 5833, 5834, 5852, 5853, 5855, 5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5910, 5913, 5914, 5938, 5959, 5964, 5975, 5978, 6021, 6022, 6023, 6026, 6027, 6028, 6029, 6030, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6034, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6046, 6094, 6099, 6100, 6105, 6109, 6111, 6113, 6114, 6115, 6116, 6152, 6153, 6158, 6159, 6160, 6161, 6162, 6163, 6164, 6165, 6166, 6174, 6243, 6324, 6325, 6415, 6416, 6527, 6533, 6534, 6539, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6559, 6581, 6582, 6583, 6584, 6631, 6632, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6671, 6672, 6673, 6674, 6675, 6676, 6681, 6690, 6692, 6693, 6694, 6797, 6798, 6799, 6899, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6954, 6959, 6960, 6964, 6970, 6971, 7246, 7247, 7248, 7250, 7251, 7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257, 7258, 7269, 7272, 7273, 7275, 7276, 7504, 7505, 7506, 7507, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7513, 7514, 7519, 7529, 7533, 7534, 7535, 7536, 7559, 7658, 7661, 7665, 7668, 7669, 7673, 7676, 7677, 7678, 7682, 7684, 7716, 7762, 7776, 7779, 7828, 7829, 7845, 7852, 7882, 7885, 7887, 7891, 7893, 7895, 7897, 7901, 7903, 7904, 7940, 7941, 7942, 7943, 8098, 8099, 8131, 8134, 8138, 8141, 8143, 8149, 8150, 8151, 8152, 8153, 8155, 8156, 8157, 8158, 8222, 8241, 8327, 8328, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8470, 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8484, 8487, 8488, 8556, 8910, 8914, 8916, 8921, 8923, 8924, 8925, 8926, 8929, 8932, 8933, 8934, 8936, 8937, 8938, 8939, 9311, 9383, 9385, 9388, 9389, 9391, 9394, 9395, 9396, 9399, 9400, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9405, 9406),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p2209 FOR VALUES IN (2209),
            schemaname_removed.tablename_removed_p2210 FOR VALUES IN (2210),
            [...]

So my questions are:
(A) How can my DB have a partition definition that is 'too big' but still work?
(B) Why could I initially create those partitions? Was the column where postgres stores the partitioning clause wider in 14.10? Why could I upgrade to 16.3 without an issue? Reading this postgres mailing list thread, the upgrade should have failed already?
(C) How can I get that restore to work without splitting my partitions?

you better know the pg and tools configuration. i mean build configuration. you updated without issues because of how your package manager works. you shall clarify with your distribution maintainers about your issue.

First thing I would do is do the minor upgrade to 16.4 and try again. If that does not work then file an bug here Bug report. FYI, you will need to setup a community account to access the form.
